# Problem with AES encrypt in javascript and Decrypt in java

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I want to encrypt and decrypt "ABCD1234" in AES but the output is not the same.
What I have to do to get the same results?

encrypt in crypto-js

```
function encrypt(string) {
  const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("g@eNR@2H'9n/ZF8s");
  const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(string, key, {
    iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("Fa6Fy$F8.qRvHKU+"),
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding
  });
  return encrypted.toString()
}

document.getElementById("encrypted").innerHTML = encrypt("ABCD1234");
```

then the output is sRdk5O4U+WA=

when i try to decrypt in java

```
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "sRdk5O4U+WA=";
        String key = "g@eNR@2H'9n/ZF8s";
        String iv = "Fa6Fy$F8.qRvHKU+";
        try 
        {
            byte[] encrypted1  = Base64.getDecoder().decode(data);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
            SecretKeySpec keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);


            byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(encrypted1);

            String decrypt = new String(original).trim();
            System.out.println("decrypt "+decrypt);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("e "+e.toString());
        }
  }
}
```

throws an exception javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length not multiple of 16 bytes

java code: https://repl.it/repls/NoxiousWavyMp3

javascript code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ydEpZB

Comment: Did you try with some padding? Something like `PKCS5Padding`, for instance? With AES you are only able to encrypt data in blocks of 128 bits (or 16 bytes).

Comment: but PKCS5Padding does not exist in cryptojs

Comment: But `PKCS#7` does, and in Java, `PKCS#5` is _equivalent_ to that (for `AES`).

Comment: with pkcs#7 for cryptojs and pkcs#5 for java everything is ok. This means I cannot use NoPadding?

Comment: You can definitely use it, but you need to understand the implications of that...basically you would have to implement your own padding (for encryption), and also account for that by removing it after decryption.